# How to redirect to same place on page when redirecting to previous page

Tags: python, django

I was wondering if there is a way in django for when you click back to go to the previous page via a link or in my case an anchored link with in an img, for it to also end up in the same place as you click originally, in my case the image that is clicked in the first place.

**Page I click image to redirect:**

```
 </head>
  <body>
    <header>{% include 'navbardesktop.html' %}</header>
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image-post">
        <a href="{% url 'gallery' %}"
          ><img class="photo-img" src="{{photo.image.url}}"
        /></a>
        <h2 class="photo-title">{{photo.image_title}}</h2>
        <p class="contact">
          Interested in purchasing this as a print? Contact me for more
          information regarding price and sizes.
        </p>
        <a href="{% url 'contact' %}" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"
          >Contact</a
        >
        <a href="{% url 'gallery' %}" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"
          >Gallery</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Page I want to redirect to:**

```
  <body>
    <header>{% include 'navbardesktop.html' %}</header>
    <div class="container-gallery">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="gallerygrid1">
        <div class="row">
          {% for photo in images %}
          <div class="col-md-4" id="gallerygrid2">
            <a href="{% url 'viewimage' photo.slug %}"
              ><img
                class="gallery-thumbnail"
                src="{{photo.image.url}}"
                style=""
            /></a>
          </div>
          {% empty %}
          <h3>No Projects...</h3>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a js event on the element that takes you to the other page and then add inClick event which will store the amount of the current scrolling in local storage and when you go back it will check the amount of scrolling that stored in the browser's local storage and do the scroll.